# Python Multiple criteria Countifs with conditions row by row

Tags: python, pandas, countif

[image]

In Excel I have the count with relative (not absolute) reference Historical Wins

```
= COUNTIFS($D3:$D$13,$D2,$E3:$E$13,1)
```

How do I loop through all of the rows, and counting the historical occurrences of wins (i.e. Pos = 1) that a particular trainer has in Python (exclude the current result)?
Is this possible?

Comment: kindly post data, not pics and with expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can get similar results as `countifs` by doing this. Can you try

`df[(df['columname']==D2) & (df['columname']==1)].shape[0]`

Here `D2` is whatever value you are trying to get the count of in the first column.

Edited based on the comment. This is for multiple values of `D2`
`df.groupby(['D2_column_name']).count()`
This will give you the count of all values of D2. You can do `groupby` on multiple columns

Comment: I think there might be two problems with this approach in here, D2 is not fixed and will be subject to change as we move down each row, think we need to use apply function in here, secondly your suggestion will just count the all of the occurrences rather than historical occurrences (i.e. relative references and not fixed or absolute reference in excel)

Comment: Please check the modified answer

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but this will still not work. Use groupby and count column d will give the counts of all wins rather than wins by trainer , i have tried to use cuncount(ascending =False) to give the historical wins for all trainers, but cannot think of a python code that will give me historical wins by trainer.

Comment: You have to filter historical wins by trainer first then do the groupby. `df[df['historic_win']==1].groupby(['D2_column_name']).count()`